# Assigning specific values in the data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to filter my data. Below you can see how is look like my data.

```
df<-data.frame(  
          Description=c("15","11","12","NA","Total","NA","9","18","NA","Total"),
          Value=c(158,196,NA,156,140,693,854,NA,904,925))

df
```

Now I want to filter and assign some text in an additional column. Desired output is need to look like the table shown below. Namely, I want to introduce additional columns with the title `Sales`.In this column, with the if-else statement, I want to introduce two categorical values. First is `Sold` and the second is `Unsold`.The first rows **until row** `'Total'` needs to have the value 'Sold' and other values under this need to have `Unsold`.

[image]

I tried to do this with this command but unfortunately is not work that I expected.

```
df1$Sales <- ifelse(df$Description==c('Total'),'Sold','Unsold')
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this?

Comment: one way can be `df1$Sales <- "Unsold";` then `df1$Sales[1:match("Total", df$Description)]<-"Sold"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
df$Sales <- ifelse(cumsum(dplyr::lag(df$Description, default = "") == "Total") > 0, 
                   "Unsold", 
                   "Sold")
df
#>    Description Value  Sales
#> 1           15   158   Sold
#> 2           11   196   Sold
#> 3           12    NA   Sold
#> 4           NA   156   Sold
#> 5        Total   140   Sold
#> 6           NA   693 Unsold
#> 7            9   854 Unsold
#> 8           18    NA Unsold
#> 9           NA   904 Unsold
#> 10       Total   925 Unsold
```

To break down the logic:

1. `dplyr::lag` checks whether the previous entry was `"Total"`. Setting a default of any string other than `"Total"` prevents creating `NA` as the first entry, because that would carry over an unwanted `NA` into the next step.
2. `cumsum` returns how many times `"Total"` has been seen as the previous entry.
3. Checking that the result of `cumsum` is greater than 0 turns step 2 into a binary result: `"Total"` has either been found, or it hasn't.
4. If `"Total"` has been found, it's unsold; otherwise it's sold.

You could also rearrange things:

```
dplyr::lag(cumsum(df$Description == "Total") < 1, default = TRUE)
```

gets the same result, with the true & false results in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

If you know there are as many `sold` as `unsold` you can use the first solution.

If you want to allow for uneven and unknown numbers of each you could use the second solution.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# FIRST SOLUTION
df |>
  mutate(Sales = ifelse(row_number() <= nrow(df) / 2, "Sold", "Unsold"))

# SECOND SOLUTION
df |>
  mutate(o = Description == "Total") |>
  mutate(Sales = ifelse(row_number() > match(TRUE, o), "Unsold", "Sold")) |>
  select(-o)
#>    Description Value  Sales
#> 1           15   158   Sold
#> 2           11   196   Sold
#> 3           12    NA   Sold
#> 4           NA   156   Sold
#> 5        Total   140   Sold
#> 6           NA   693 Unsold
#> 7            9   854 Unsold
#> 8           18    NA Unsold
#> 9           NA   904 Unsold
#> 10       Total   925 Unsold
```